# Func detegate is not working with Entity Fromework

Tags: c#

i am using entity fromework 6 and func is not working in right way here is my code

```
DbSet<vExpenseRegister> dbSet1 = Context.Set<vExpenseRegister>();
// got db set from dbcontext, it is ok

Func<vExpenseRegister, bool> where= a => a.InvoiceDate > fromDate;
// create a delegate and pass a condition

var result = dbSet1.Where(where).AsQueryable().ToList();

// but result is nothing, in spite of record exists in database 
//but i change code eliminate Func delegate and condition write in where method //like

var result = dbSet1.Where(a => a.InvoiceDate > fromDate).AsQueryable().ToList();
//working fine
```

kindly help me why Func is not working

Thanks,
Akmal.

Comment: Func line is not show properly here is right code

Comment: Func@<vExpenseRegister, bool2> predicate = a => a.InvoiceDate > fromDate;

Comment: Func<vExpenseRegister, bool> predicate = a => a.InvoiceDate > fromDate;

Answer (score 0):

This should be an `Expression<Func<...>>`:

```
Func<vExpenseRegister, bool> where= a => a.InvoiceDate > fromDate;
```

So

```
Expression<Func<vExpenseRegister, bool>> where = a => a.InvoiceDate > fromDate;
```

If it is just a `Func<...>` it will be executed in memory after the entire table is returned.

If you look at the signature of `dbSet1.Where` you should see it takes an expression.